# Fluent Nhibernate and quartz

Tags: nhibernate, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I'm building a asp.net mvc web application. And I'm running quartz in the asp.net context.
I'm using fluent nhibernate for my or mappings.
I'm building a simple job that goes writes an entry in the database.

```
    public void Execute(JobExecutionContext context)
    {

        ISession session = DataSourceConfiguration.GetSessionFactory().OpenSession();
        session.SaveOrUpdate(new JobLogEntry() { Created = DateTime.Now, Message = "Twitter feed read" });
        session.Close();
        session.Dispose();
    }

    public static ISessionFactory GetSessionFactory()
    {
        return Fluently.Configure()
          .Database(CurrentDataBaseConfiguration)
          .Mappings(m =>
            m.AutoMappings.Add(
              AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Entry>()
                .Where(t => t.Namespace == "QuickBlog.BlogModel.Entities")
            ))
          .BuildSessionFactory(); 
    }
```

Here is where the error occurs:

```
    public static IPersistenceConfigurer CurrentDataBaseConfiguration
    {
        get
        {
            if (_dataBaseConfiguration != null)
                return _dataBaseConfiguration;


                var config = MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005
                    .ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("QuickBlogDB"))
                    .UseReflectionOptimizer()
                    .Cache(c => c.Not
                    .UseQueryCache())
                    .ShowSql(); 

                _dataBaseConfiguration = config;


            return _dataBaseConfiguration;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("QuickBlogDB") is null or empty. How do I get a hold of the configuration info in the quartz.net job?

Comment: Is Quartz running inside the context of the ASP.NET MVC app, or in a separate service?

Comment: Its running inside the context of the asp.net mvc. I want to access the connection string in web.config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you probably should not create your session factory inside your job. I would recommend of having a static class to hold session factory and initialize it in earlier stage, say applications Application_Start method.

It's more resource efficient (a lot) and makes it easier to debug problems as your app won't even start before configuration and preconditions are right.